# Applying patch to the uClibc

Tags: compiling, patch, buildroot

I have a buildroot package that I need to build. When I issue the 'make' command, it runs until it errors out with "lutimes undeclared". After lengthy research, it appears that uClibc needs to be patched to include the definition of lutimes before my build will complete.

I found this patch, but being new to Linux, I do not know how to apply it:
[ucLibc Mailing List Archive - June 2010, Post 44113](http://lists.uclibc.org/pipermail/uclibc/2010-June/044113.html)

Can I properly apply this patch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have in mind that Patches are per source code revision, and after 4 years of changes in the source code, this patch may be outdated and may need recreation from scratch.

First thing you should do is check the official documentation.
http://buildroot.uclibc.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_providing_patches

You should pay attention to the following two categories:
17.1.2. Within Buildroot
and
17.2. How patches are applied

Give it a try and let us know if you face any issues

Comment: It talks about patches within the buildroot package, where are they ?

Comment: Check out 9.8. Customizing packages
Basicly you need to check the info, make yourself clear how patches are used by this buildroot, put your patch there as an THERE_IS_A_NAME_CONVENTION.patch file in the right path, and start from beginning of compiling this buildroot.
libc takes a lot of time to compile as far as I remember.

Comment: Sorry man :/ couldn't find the patches. Can you help me a little further in this ?